# How to generate multiple legacy or segwit bitcoin address

Tags: bitcoin-core, command-line-options

I would like to generate multiple bitcoin (and litecoin) addresses via Bitcoin Core (and Litecoin Core). I saw this topic [How can I generate a large number of Bitcoin addresses?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/1836/how-can-i-generate-a-large-number-of-bitcoin-addresses) but "keypool" does not work in the Bitcoin Core console (which is accessible with CTRL+T or in Window menu>Console). I saw that I can generate new address with this command line : getnewaddress label addresstype but it's a little bit long because I want to generate at least 100 address for each address type.

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to generate at least 100 address for each address type

You can use `for` loop to create 100 bech32 addresses in default wallet('bech32' can be replaced with 'legacy or 'p2sh-segwit':

Linux:

```
for i in {1..100}; do bitcoin-cli -rpcwallet="" getnewaddress " " "bech32"; done
```

Windows (PowerShell):

```
 for ($i=1; $i -le 100; $i++) {.\bitcoin-cli -rpcwallet="" getnewaddress " " "bech32"}
```