# How do I create multiple Bitcoin addresses and send coins to other addresses from linux console?

Tags: bitcoind, bitcoin-cli, address-generation

I want to be able to create many Bitcoin addresses and transfer coins from those addresses to other addresses.
It is better if it is available on a Linux server, through the command line.
What libraries or programs might work for this?

Comment: It might be relevant what level of activity you're expecting, as very high activity could exclude some solutions that would be good choices for lower volume.

Answer (score 0):

Create multiple address: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/107735/133407

You can send coin to those addresses using signet faucet: https://signet.bc-2.jp/

Create a transaction to transfer coins:

```
$ bitcoin-cli createpsbt "[{\"txid\":\"myid\",\"vout\":0}]" "[{\"<address>\":\"<amount>\"}]"
```

You would have to finalize the PSBT using `finalizepsbt` after signing

Broadcast it using:

```
$ bitcoin-cli sendrawtransaction "signedhex"
```

Comment: Can I send coins to addresses created by someone else?

Comment: Yes, but then the coins are yours. That's how you generally transfer BTC.